# Pandas dataframe contains then replace dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with columns A and B. I want to say for each row if A contains "Fred" then B is called "Blue".

I can do this with this line

```
df.loc[df['A'].str.contains('Fred'),'B']='Blue'
```

I would like to do this in a loop of a dictionary.

so

```
dict = {'Fred':'blue','Jess':'red','David':'Green'}
```

how would I turn this into a loop?

Example df

```
0   FREDDDD     xxx
1   dfdfa       dfdf
2   dfdf        dfsd
3   GFDFJESS    sdfedf
4   sdfdsfds    dsfd
```

Expected output

```
0   FREDDDD     blue
1   dfdfa       dfdf
2   dfdf        dfsd
3   GFDFJESS    red
4   sdfdsfds    dsfd
```

Comment: Does `dic` always only have two entries?

Comment: no, it will have loads

Comment: just did 2 for the example

Comment: Okay, in this case what if A contains anything besides Fred and Jess?

Comment: I see what you're getting at, but there will be alot more outputs, than TRUE and FALSE. so Fred=1, Jess=2,George=Blue,Matt=car etc

Comment: Should these be full word matches? For example, should "Jess" match "Jessie"? Should "Fred" match "Fred Flintstone"? Lots of holes in your question...

Comment: yes, contains not full match

Comment: Final question: if nothing is matched, is the result NaN?

Comment: yeah would be fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `findall` with `map` , then assign it back

```
s=df.A.str.findall('|'.join(dic.keys())).str[0].map(dic)
df.loc[s.notnull(),'B']=s
df
Out[1077]: 
           A     B
0  Fred llll  blue
1      CHECK     1
2   Jess mmm   red
3      CHECK     3
4        efg   NaN
5        ijk     3
6        lmn     1
7        opq     7
```

Answer (score 4):

Let's use `str.extract` with `Series.map`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['Fred Flintstone', 'Jessie', 'Jess abcxyz', 'something else']})
df

                 A
0  Fred Flintstone
1           Jessie
2      Jess abcxyz
3   something else
```

```
p = r'({})'.format('|'.join(dic.keys()))
df['A'].str.extract(p, expand=False).map(dic)

0     TRUE
1    FALSE
2    FALSE
3      NaN
Name: A, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 3):

Use something like:

```
print(df) #dummy dataframe

    Name  some_col
0   Fred       1.0
1  CHECK       1.0
2   Jess       NaN
3  CHECK       3.0
4    efg       NaN
5    ijk       3.0
6    lmn       1.0
7    opq       7.0

d=dict(zip(df.Name,df.Name.str.contains('Fred')))
print(d)

{'Fred': True,
'CHECK': False,
 'Jess': False,
 'efg': False,
 'ijk': False,
 'lmn': False,
 'opq': False}
```